# Print a text pattern in java

Tags: java

I need the pattern to be printed in the form

```
   ABCDEF FEDCBA
   ABCDE   EDCBA
   ABCD     DCBA
   ABC       CBA
   AB         BA
   A           A
```

Below is my code :

```
   public static void main(String args[])
{
    char[] c = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G'};
    int i, j;

    for(j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(c[k]);
        }
        for(i = j; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(c[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Which gives me the output as

```
   ABCDEFFEDCBA
   ABCDEEDCBA
   ABCDDCBA
   ABCCBA
   ABBA
   AA
```

It was fairly easy to reach to this output. However, i haven't been able to provide spaces. I know the loop to produce the space will come in between both the for loops but i couldn't figure out how to do it. Its bugging me for a while.

Comment: Just print the right number of spaces? Seems like it should be calculable since you know it's relative to the number of letters total.

Comment: You need to print a space character `6-j` times inside your outer-loop between your two inner-loops.

Comment: Why does your array contain `'G'` ?

Comment: @Quentin Ugh i didnt notice that. Will edit it.

Answer (score 5):

I give you hint, count the spaces :

For line 1 : 1 spaces

For line 2 : 3 spaces

For line 3 : 5 spaces

For line 4 : 7 spaces

etc., see the pattern? :)

And yes, put one more "space for cycle" between existing for cycles.

---

Spoiler ALERT, here is Java solution, but try to do it without it.

This is fully working code, it also works with any size of array :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char[] c = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Y', 'Z'};
    int i, j;

    for (j = c.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++) {
            System.out.print(c[k]);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < (c.length-j)*2 - 1; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (i = j; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(c[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Sample output :

```
ABCDEFGYZ ZYGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGY   YGFEDCBA
ABCDEFG     GFEDCBA
ABCDEF       FEDCBA
ABCDE         EDCBA
ABCD           DCBA
ABC             CBA
AB               BA
A                 A
```

Comment: yeah i think the old school method of writing down the logic like a pseudo code will be a lot better of figuring it out than to simply edit and debug. Well thanks for reminding me that one.

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] c = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G'};
    int i, j,n,p=1;

    for(j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(c[k]);
        }
        for(n = 1; n <= p; n++)
        System.out.print(" ");
        p+=2;
        for(i = j; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(c[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though there are some (already) answered solutions, too many loops increase the complexity:

```
char[] c = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G' };

for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  String tmp = String.valueOf(c).substring(0, c.length - i);

  System.out.printf("%s %" + (c.length + i) + "s%n", tmp, new StringBuilder(tmp).reverse());
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ABCDEFG GFEDCBA
ABCDEF   FEDCBA
ABCDE     EDCBA
ABCD       DCBA
ABC         CBA
AB           BA
A             A
```

Your `char` array can be increased any time, the output would be "the same" (in terms of formatting).

Comment: The complexity is same in both cases :), but +1 vote for very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Each row of your pattern is of fixed width: 13 characters. That means that if you print `j` characters (index of your outer loop), you need to print `13-2*j` spaces.

```
for (int k=0; k<13-2*j; k++){
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a new variable `max` to set up `j` initially. This variable is used for the `len` calculation for the spaces.

```
char[] c = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G'};
int i, j;

int max = 5; //your max output (could be 6)
for(j = max; j >= 0; j--)
{
    for(int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
    {
        System.out.print(c[k]);
    }
    int len = max*2+1; //length calculation
    for(int x = 0; x < len-2*j; x++){ //space loop
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(i = j; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print(c[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: So, somehow you came to knew i had problem with keeping j in check. Well now i know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please use proper names for your variables. Java is not Basic, so you can use up to 65,535 characters in a variable name if you wish.

Documentation through code helps people who have to maintain code in the future.

```
public class PrintChars {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    char[] chars = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' };
    int length = chars.length;

    for (int row = length; row > 0; row--) {
      for (int left = 0; left < row; left++) {
        System.out.print(chars[left]);
      }
      for (int space = 0; space < (length-row)*2+1; space++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
      }
      for (int right = row-1; right >= 0; right--) {
        System.out.print(chars[right]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGH HGFEDCBA
ABCDEFG   GFEDCBA
ABCDEF     FEDCBA
ABCDE       EDCBA
ABCD         DCBA
ABC           CBA
AB             BA
A               A
```

Comment: Does makes sense. At least will mention in comments what variables stand for from now on.